# Sanity check my Rails "Roles and Users" approach with Devise and Cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, roles

been kicking this one about for a while now, and would like to get someone who knows rails to test my theory (I'm new to Rails).

In my (simplified) scenario, I want to manage a list of Users, some of which are, for example, "paid" users, some are "free" users etc, and there is a straight "isa" relationship. i.e. a paid user isa user, a free user isa user etc

To reduce redundancy and to keep it semantically correct, I want to manage all the users in one table and use a foreign-key back to the correct "type" of user, so I can create a role of the correct type. e.g. I would instantiate a User, get the id and store this in the user of correct type e.g. "PaidUser" in the "user_id" foreign-key. This gives me the ability to store specific metadata I want to store against them, and I don't have to have one table ("users") with every field for every type of user.

This sort of feels like a confusion of roles and types of users. My question is, is using the approach above going to make life difficult? Is there an accepted approach to this in Rails that I'm missing? I'm using Devise and have removed all routes except for /users/ thinking I would pass a "type" as an argument, and use that type to create the corresponding "real" type of record at the same time as the user. Is this bad practice too?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing sounds fine, but to be honest unless you have a lot of these different properties between user types I would just put them all in the same table. It's not really a big deal to have a couple of blank columns here and there, especially when it saves you from having to do a whole load of difficult stuff. If this starts to seem unwieldy then you can worry about what to do then - it would still be easy to change. You could even then potentially use Single Table Inheritance to give all the different user types their own class that inherits from the base `User` class, which is where you take care of all the authentication etc.

If you immediately go with something more complex then it will be much harder to unravel if it turns out to be wrong than if you start with something simple. If you go with the multi-table approach then make sure you name them sensibly. I would go with `PaidUserProfile` etc.

Comment: haha, thanks RobHeaton, appreciate it, you've made me feel much better about that approach. If you did that, what would you recommend to manage all the different possible states (if a user has many roles)? CanCan has the nice Many-to-many https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Separate-Role-Model design I was intending to use - storing all types of users in a single table shouldn't preclude that right?

Comment: No not at all, if anything it will make it easier because the relationship won't have to be polymorphic in any way.